# Shortcodes in Woocommerce editor are not displayed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, shortcode

I'm trying to create a custom tab for my Woocommerce page, which works so far and displays also the content on the front page. The problem is that it ignores shortcodes and html values. So it will display them just as written. So when I write `<strong>Test</strong>` it will display it just like that and by adding visual composer shortcodes, it's also displaying them 1:1. How can I use shortcodes with the editor? I tried already to change the input field

**from**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'wp_bibel_de_add_custom_product_field' );

function wp_bibel_de_add_custom_product_field() {
    woocommerce_wp_textarea_input( 
        array( 
            'id'          => '_custom_tab_description', 
            'label'       => __( 'Custom Tab Description' )
        )
    );
}
```

**to**

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'wp_amaoni_de_add_custom_product_field');

function wp_amaoni_de_add_custom_product_field() {

    global $post;

    $content = $post->post_content;
    $editor_id = '_custom_tab_description';

    wp_editor($content, $editor_id);
}
```

So that i get a WYSIWG Editor. But still, same problem. Shortcodes aren't working

**Code that i have at the moment**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'wp_bibel_de_add_custom_product_field' );

function wp_bibel_de_add_custom_product_field() {
    woocommerce_wp_textarea_input( 
        array( 
            'id'          => '_custom_tab_description', 
            'label'       => __( 'Custom Tab Description' )
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'wp_bibel_de_save_custom_product_field' );

function wp_bibel_de_save_custom_product_field( $post_id ){

    $custom_tab_description = $_POST['_custom_tab_description'];

    if( !empty( $custom_tab_description ) ) :
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_custom_tab_description', esc_html( $custom_tab_description ) );
    endif; 
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'wp_bibel_de_add_woocommerce_product_tabs' );

function wp_bibel_de_add_woocommerce_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
    $tabs['wp_bibel_de_custom_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'New Product Tab' ),
        'priority'  => 50,
        'callback'  => 'wp_bibel_de_new_product_tab_callback'
    );

    return $tabs;
}

function wp_bibel_de_new_product_tab_callback() {
    global $post;

    echo wpautop( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_custom_tab_description', true ) ); 
}
```